# Tree view layout in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I am creating a `treeview` in asp.net and able to bind `treeview` perfectly.But my tree view is looks the following image which is as default layout of treeview control.
[image]

I am using the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("div[id=tvCategories] input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
                $(this).closest('table').next('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);

                $(this).parents('div').each(function (index) {
                    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checkbox').length > 0) {
                        $(this).prev('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
                    }
                });
            });

        });

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TreeView ID="tvCategories" NodeIndent="25"  OnTreeNodeDataBound="tvCategories_TreeNodeDataBound"   Style="font-family: 'Lato', 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 50px; color: Black; font-size: 12px"
                    runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All">

                </asp:TreeView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But I want need the following layout. which I am not able to create this

[image]

Please help me to create this.Is `Trieeview` control is match for this layout or bind it by other way ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are intending to do is not possible to elegantly do because of the default HTML that is rendered by the TreeView control (Table -> Div -> Table, Div etc).

You could however use a CSS control adaptor to change the way the default HTML is rendered (Ul -> Li -> Ul -> Li). The HTML that is rendered using this approach is nested and therefore can be targeted using CSS to attain the look you are seeking to achieve. You may have to rewrite some of your code and create a custom implementation.

See http://samples.asp.net/cssadapters/TreeView.aspx for code examples.

I hope that helps!